Polars read_database does not respect iter_batches = True when using sqlalchemy/oracledb
This query using polars and sqlalchemy does not fetch chunked.
d = pl.read_database(sql_text(sql), e, iter_batches=True, batch_size=1000000)

The connection is a sqlalchemy create_engine("oracle+oracledb://@xxx") on top of oracledb.
It fetches every 2 billion rows, or tries to, ending in a memoryerror. Any way of getting the message through to the engine to do batched fetches in another way?

Same thing also, when the connection is just a con = oracledb.connect(), without sqlalchemy.

Might something as suggested in this answer work?

It does not solve the issue of reading batch-wise from a database in order to avoid memory  overload. I raised this issue on Polars Github yesterday: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/15470 . Pandas does the batch wise reads without exhausting memory, as is shown in the issue.

@alexander-beedie has posted a fix. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/15504

Is now fixed, yes. Not an issue anymore
